# Finding equilibrium points with two equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am given the following two differential equations and asked to find the equilibrium points, I've looked on Pauls online notes; however, I could not find anything that was similar to my problem, any suggestions on how to attempt it would be helpful

$$x’ = 5- 0.01 x + 0.0025 y$$

$$y’ = 10 + 0.01 x – 0.01 y$$

Comment: The equilibrium points should be when $x' = y' =0$. Does that help?

Comment: I understand that part; however, i am confused on how to go about it. The equations govern the rate of sugar in two separate tanks. if it were a simple quadratic I would see how easy it would be to find the values that make the equations zero , but having both the x and y in the di/dt or dy/dt equations leave me dumbfounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, $x'= y'=0$ when
\begin{align}
-0.01x &&+0.0025y &= -5, \\
0.01x && - 0.01y &= -10.
\end{align}
You can see we can add equations these to obtain $-0.0075y= -15$, so $y = 2000$. This gives $0.01x = -10 + 0.01(2000) = -10 + 20 =10,$ so $x= 1000$.

Comment: wouldn't x be 1000?

Comment: yes. corrected.